# Python setuptools entry_points location

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, entry-point

If I declare a custom entry point, how to locate it in a sub-directory? With a standard syntax:

```
setup(                                                                 
     name="valid_parser",                                           
     version="0.0.0",                                               
     py_modules=['api', 'internal'],                                
     entry_points={'parsers': ['valid_parser.api = api', ]}
     )
```

the module declared as an entry point will be located in `lib/python2.7/site-packages/api.py`. If any other package will declare an entry_point with the same name the old one be overwritten. I'd rather have such a path `lib/python2.7/site-packages/package_name/api.py`.

I guess a couple of ways how it could be possible but haven't found any information about the topic. Is there an option for pip or `setup` function? Or can I override a `Command` class to customize a path?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a misunderstanding here. One entry point can contain several scripts - see `console_scripts` here https://github.com/websauna/websauna/blob/master/setup.py#L130 - Also maybe you need more namespace to entry point name themselves if you are afraid there could be a conflict.